# Make a form responsive into a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a form responsive and load it into a div, so that the form takes the shape of the div without over floating. I have applied row-fluid to the form element and the div and it still not responsive as shown

```
var div_container = document.getElementById('active-container');
                var users = '';
                var formy = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
                    users += '<span style="font-size:27px;"><strong>' + json[i].email + '</strong></span><br/>' + '<form class="row-fluid" style="margin-top:0px;" method="post" action="search"><input class="row-fluid" type="text" value="'+json[i].access+'" name="searchName" id="searchName" readonly/><button class="btn btn-success" type="submit"><i class="icon-circle-arrow-right icon-large"></i>FETCH</button></form>' + '<hr>';
                 }
```

EDITTED: 
This is the div for the containing form tag

```
<div style="overflow: auto; overflow-x: auto; height:420px; color:#4b4f54; font-size:13px;" id="active-container">
        </div>
```

Please how do I make the responsive into the div and attach the button to the right of the input type

Comment: Are you using `bootstrap` ? there are pre-defined classes for it.

Comment: What does your markup look like?

Comment: Which markup please

Comment: Your html code.

Comment: Post the `HTML` code or other markup in which you are building the layout .

Comment: Just editted to rreflect the html code of the div

Comment: @Francis not sure why you are using JS but I did just post a more simple approach,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use something as simple as this. No JS needed.

**Updated:** inline style added. Also you can adjust by % within the inline styling, which I have found useful.

**The markup**

```
<div class="container">
<h2>Form name</h2>
    <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input style="display:inline; width:75%" type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email">
            <button style="width:24%"type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Fetch</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**The CSS:** adjust max-width as needed or remove altogether.

```
.container {
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 10px 10px;
  max-width: 500px;
  background: #FDFDFD;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px #D8D8D8;
}
```

[JsFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/norcaljohnny/bLc4eue1/)

[Float left Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/norcaljohnny/65ewcodb/)

Comment: follow the problem statement

Comment: My apologizes, I did not make it inline. Check update.

Comment: '<div class="container"><div class="form-group"><input style="display:inline; width:15%" type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email"><button style="width:24%"type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Fetch</button></div></form></div>';

Comment: Using the above, can I float the button to the left

Comment: On reducing the width the button becomes spaced out from the input element

Comment: To float left change the pull-right to pull-left. As far as spacing, get rid of the padding left/right and adjust the %. I did that to show it is in a div and the outlines of the div.

Comment: @Francis I added a float left demo, removed the padding-left/right and % totals 100 now.

Comment: '<div class="container"><form><div class="form-group"><input style="display:inline; width:75%" type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email"><button style="width:24%"type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right">Fetch</button></div> </form></div>';

Comment: That is exactly what I am using

Comment: @Francis the change is on the float left demo I added to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

use `.form-inline` to make form responsive , to make button on right use `.pull-right` class.

If you want to have input and button just aside each other just use this :-

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-sm-4 control-label">DOB - Age:</label>
            <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-4 input-group">
                <input type="text" id="" class="form-control" name="" style="margin-left:15px;" value="" tabindex="-1" />
                    <span class="input-group-btn" style="">
                       <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-angle-right" style="margin-left:15px"></i>Button</button>
                    </span>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what about the form tag

Answer (score -1):

Add class .form-inline to the  element